# Unity3D saving string data to ICloud

Tags: synchronization, cloud, unity-game-engine

I am working on game project using Unity3D and I want to save (string or binary no problem) to icloud. I need it to implement game progress synchronization. I searched the web but I couldn't find a solution. I used google play services cloud and it was very easy to use. But when I began with data upload and download, I didn't know what to do.
Any helps :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing it on iCloud you have to write your custom iOS plugin for Unity3d.

I found this plugin on github:
https://github.com/phamtanlong/unity-ios-keychain-plugin